# combine tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I am using MySql to run queries. My data in 2 million.
I have two tables:

```
USA (name, last_name, us_address, phone_number, car_no)
India (name, last_name, india_address, phone_number)
```

I want to combine both tables. As you can see, `name` and `last_name` can be in both tables, however, the `address` and `phone number` will definately be different because they are of two different countries. Also I want `car_no` in the final table too.

The new table column names will be:

```
final_name, final_last_name, address, phone
```

Any advice ?

Comment: The question is some way unclear now, please add some sample of data and the expected output you would like to get.

Comment: 'address and phone number will definately be different' is there some relevance to this statement?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? Do you want to replace these tables with a new one? Or do you only want to retrieve a combined result set while keeping both tables?

Answer (score 0):

you could use union  all

```
select name final_name, last_name final_last_name, us_address address, phone_number phone, car_no
from usa
union all
select name, last_name, india_address, phone_number , null
from india
```

Comment: this works. But I want to add the 'car_no' column too. Kindly advice

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
    select name as final_name, last_name as final_last_name, us_address as address, phone_number as phone, car_no
    from USA
    union all
    select name, last_name, india_address, phone_number , null
    from India
```